# Uploading and Viewing Photos

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help i'm using MVC 5 and doing a code on uploading and displaying photos and i'm having an error (The name ' file ' does not exist in the current content) please help

This is the controller i'm using:

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UploadViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }


        UploadDbModel fileUploadModel = new UploadDbModel();
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                byte[] uploadFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];
                model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadFile, 0, uploadFile.Length);

                fileUploadModel.FileName = model.File.FileName;
                fileUploadModel.File = uploadFile;

                db.UploadDbModels.Add(fileUploadModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Content("FILE SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED");
        }
        catch
        {
            return Content("UPLOAD FAILED");
        }

    }

    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        return View(db.UploadDbModels.ToList());
    }

    public FileContentResult FileDownload(int? id)
    {
        byte[] fileData;
        string fileName;

        UploadDbModel fileRecord = db.UploadDbModels.Find(id);

        fileData = (byte[])fileRecord.File.ToArray();
        fileName = fileRecord.FileName;

        return File(fileData, "text", fileName);
    }


}
```

Comment: In your upload method. Where is file defined? I do not see its definition...

Comment: Try searching for "does not exist in the current content". It means you're using a variable that does not exist. The variable `file` does not exist. Did you mean `if (model.file.ContentLength > 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.Net MVC we have to use `HttpPostedFileBase` for Uploaded files as shown below :-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  if (file != null)
    {
        int byteCount = file.ContentLength;   <---Your file Size or Length
        .............
        .............
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works now, and i added system.web reference it was missing

Comment: Kindly...Upvote accept answer if it is helpful to solve your problem...Thankzz...@user3891423

Answer (score 0):

Try and use system.web, just add the reference on the assembly hope it works.

Comment: The problem looks like an undeclared variable, not a missing `using` statement.